# KML for Labels in Cesium to Display Countries, States, Roads, etc

Tags: labeling, kml, overlay, cesium

Is there a free way to display countries, states, roads, etc. in Cesium? I imagine these could be displayed using a comprehensive list of ground overlays in KML. I have looked for free sources of KML or KMZ to achieve these purposes, but have come up with no leads. Do you know of any place where I can get a list of country boundaries for instance in a KML file? Am I barking up the wrong tree? Are these labels are usually packaged with map tiles?

Answer (score 1):

You may not need KML for the whole world just to get labels turned on.  Have you tried [selecting a different base imagery layer](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases&gist=f638278e5869c25571e5aa23c5f816a7)?  It's the second icon from the upper-right on the toolbar.

```
var imagery = Cesium.createDefaultImageryProviderViewModels();

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    imageryProviderViewModels: imagery,
    selectedImageryProviderViewModel: imagery[1]
});
```

Comment: That is really cool, but essentially that is loading a new set of map tiles, right?

Comment: Yes, just a base map layer.  This has the disadvantage of being raster labels, not vector labels.  I think vector label support is somewhere on the Cesium roadmap, but I don't know if or when they might show up.  Still the raster one works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an animation and live example that uses country outlines from KMZ in Cesium. The live Cesium example may take a while to load as it has 24 thousand earthquakes over the past 100 years but this examples has all the countries as vector outlines in KMZ. To access once loaded just turn off translucent layers depth 0 and depth 300k (upper left).

Animation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbXf3scNL2E

Live Cesium model with country vector outlines: http://www.hitechmex.org/cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/gallery/EQ_SubSurfaceMODrrV7.html

The vector outlines of the countries were from Google Fusion Tables, just do a google search "World Country Boundaries.kml" for the kml file. Hope this helps, Reuben